# Can't run iOS app with libxml2 and hpple in physical device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode

favorite
This question is an exact duplicate of:
Unable to compile Objective C in Swift project for physical iOS device
I created a Swift 3 app in XCode 8. It uses hpple (Objective-C) to parse an HTML page.

It has always worked in virtual simulators, but some hours ago I tried to run it in a physical iPhone 4s (iOS 9.3)

The result is below: 
[image: errors]

How can I fix that? Is that a build problem?

Comment: hpple has to be build for this new target

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: I didn't find the answer. I searched a lot in Stack Overflow, but I couldn't find anything useful for me. I also tried to create a new target, but I dont't know what have to be different. Can you please post a link to the correct answer? Thank you

Comment: Note that I've always had issues with hpple in Swift when I was using it - I've since then switched to Fuzi https://github.com/cezheng/Fuzi which works flawlessly with a Swift codebase - maybe it can help you if you're fed up with hpple. Anyway, building hpple's scheme is supposed to be the solution for your issue.

Comment: I tried that, but I keep getting that error: http://it.tinypic.com/r/x5z4af/9